# AJAX form refreshes page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Have been searching around for a while and can't find a proper answer to this problem. I have a "finance" tracker that has several hidden divs which using jQuery appear when the button to show that div is clicked. I have a Asset Tracker which queries a database and upon being checked updates the database with new values in adjacent input rows where the checkbox is located. I am trying to get the checkbox to submit the data without causing the page to reload and the div to "toggle" off again.

On the form section I attempted to remove the `method='post'` but instead when checking the box it reloaded the page and added all the post variables to the URL string. I removed the `action='FBook.php'` in an attempt to prevent the reloading, but that did not resolve the problem.

Here is the related code from the PHP file:

```
if(isset($_POST['AssetSetUpdate'])) { $AssetLastUpdate = $dtNowDate->format('Y-m-d');
foreach($_POST['AssetID'] as $key => $id) { if(isset($_POST['AssetSetUpdate'][$key])) {
$stmt_ATrackUp -> bindParam(':UpDate', $AssetLastUpdate, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
$stmt_ATrackUp -> bindParam(':UpNotes', $_POST['AssetNotes'][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$stmt_ATrackUp -> bindParam(':UpThis', $_POST['AssetDescription'][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
$stmt_ATrackUp -> bindParam(':UpVal', $_POST['AssetValue'][$key], PDO::PARAM_INT, 3);
$stmt_ATrackUp -> execute(); } else continue; }
echo "<div class='Notice'>" . $PageTitle . " / Assets updated!</div>"; }
```

(other code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#AssetUpdateForm").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
     url: 'FBook.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
     success: function() { alert('form submitted'); },
    });
return false;
});


$('#ShFBAsset').click(function() { $('#FBAsset').toggle('slow'); });
```

(other code)

```
});
```

(other code)

```
$AssetCounter = 1;

$stmt_ATrack -> execute(); while ($row_ATrack = $stmt_ATrack -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

{   

$ChAge = $row_ATrack['Checked']; $cChAge = ''; switch(true)
{
case (strtotime($ChAge) >= strtotime('-7 days')): $cChAge = 'FBCAN'; break;
case (strtotime($ChAge) >= strtotime('-30 days')): $cChAge = 'FBCA1'; break;
case (strtotime($ChAge) >= strtotime('-90 days')): $cChAge = 'FBCA3'; break;
default: $cChAge = 'FBCA6'; break;
}

if(isset($row_ATrack['Serial'])) { $IfDSerial = "<strong>Serial: </strong>" . $row_ATrack['Serial'] . "<br/>"; } else { $IfDSerial = ''; }
if(isset($row_ATrack['UPC'])) { $IfDUPC = "<strong>UPC: </strong>" . $row_ATrack['UPC'] . "<br/>"; } else { $IfDUPC = ''; }
if(isset($row_ATrack['Related'])) { $IfDRelated = "<strong>Related: </strong>" . $row_ATrack['Related'] . "<br/>"; } else { $IfDRelated = ''; }
if(isset($row_ATrack['Location'])) { $IfDLocation = "<strong>Location: </strong>" . $row_ATrack['Location'] . "<br/>"; } else { $IfDLocation = ''; }
if(isset($row_ATrack['TagPhoto'])) { $IfDTagPhoto = "<strong>Tag photo: </strong><a href='Images/INV/" . $row_ATrack['TagPhoto'] . ".JPG'>" . $row_ATrack['TagPhoto'] . "</a><br/>"; } else { $IfDTagPhoto = ''; }

$IfDetails = "<div class='UPop'><img class='th_icon' src='Images/Icons/ic_lst.jpeg'><div class='UPopO'>" . ($IfDSerial) . ($IfDUPC) . ($IfDRelated) . ($IfDLocation) . ($IfDTagPhoto) . "</div></div>";
if($IfDetails == "<div class='UPop'><img class='th_icon' src='Images/Icons/ic_lst.jpeg'><div class='UPopO'></div></div>") { $IfDetails = ''; }

echo "<form id='AssetUpdateForm[" . $AssetCounter . "]' method='post'>";
echo "<tr><input type='hidden' name='AssetID[" . $AssetCounter . "]' value='" . $AssetCounter . "' />";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='AssetDescription[" . $AssetCounter . "]' value='" . $row_ATrack['Description'] . "' /><a href='https://www.google.com/#q=eBay+" . $row_ATrack['Description'] . "' target='_new_AssetSearch'>" . $row_ATrack['Description'] . "</a></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row_ATrack['Type'] . " - " . $row_ATrack['Category'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='AssetSetUpdate[" . $AssetCounter . "]' value='Now' onchange='this.form.submit();' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='number' name='AssetValue[" . $AssetCounter . "]' value = '" . $row_ATrack['Value'] . "' style='width: 75px;' /></td>";
echo "<td class='" . $cChAge . "'>" . $ChAge . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='AssetNotes[" . $AssetCounter . "]' value = '" . $row_ATrack['Notes'] . "' style='width: 140px;' /></td>";
echo "<td>" . $IfDetails . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";

$AssetCounter++;

}
```

Comment: Just for your interest, you should remove a spurious comma in the line `success: function() { alert('form submitted'); },`. JS and PHP behave differently for spurious commas, you should remove that one.

Comment: 1. Stop looking at the PHP. If the form is submitting and you don't want it to, then all that really matters if the HTML and the JavaScript. It's very hard to debug from your PHP as we now have a pile of PHP that we have to convert to HTML to figure out what is going on. 2. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/), you have some obvious errors in your HTML (such as a table row where a table row is forbidden) that could be the cause of your problem by the time the browser finishes compensating for them.

Comment: I didn't include the full code because the file is ~31 KB in size. I can - but I seriously don't think a <tr> is forbidden here because it's encased in a table. In what scenario would a <tr> prevent a ajax request? Using firebug, it shows no HTML errors, warnings, or even alerts about the ajax failing. That is what worries me, because the alert is not functioning. I assigned the form a class and called that class from the jQuery selector, and removed the extra comma. No impact to the end result. Used the w3 validator and it showed 999 errors (DIVs not allowed in DIVs, <p/> is a invalid tag?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had nothing to do with the HTML or PHP. Turns out that jQuery AJAX was conflicting with the `onclick='this.form.submit();'` property. I removed that and changed the ajax request to the following - and while it still has bugs as it won't work on the 2nd ajax request, it validates everything else is fine.

```
$(".Check2Update").on('change', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'FBook.php',
    data: $(this.form).serialize(),
    success: function(html) { 
        console.log('Successfully submitted AJAX!');
        $("#TableAssets").replaceWith($('#TableAssets', $(html)));
    }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript:

```
$("#AssetUpdateForm")
```

… is working on a form with `id="AssetUpdateForm"`.

Your PHP says:

```
id='AssetUpdateForm[" . $AssetCounter . "]'
```

which in HTML terms becomes:

```
id='AssetUpdateForm[something]'
```

Even if the variable is empty, you still have the square brackets, so the ID is not going to match and the JavaScript event handler will never be bound to that element.

You need to either use the real ID or, since it appears that it can change, add a `class` to the form and use a `.class-selector` in the JavaScript.

---

NB: Your HTML is invalid. The particular problem you have has the potential to cause the same symptoms are you describe so **just** fixing the problem above might not be enough. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) and write valid HTML too.